# Synchronizing error. Cannot access to data

Tags: ubuntu-one, sync

I have a problem with my Ubuntu One account.

When I try to connect from my desktop, I'm said that there has been a `file synchronization mistake` (in French : `erreur de synchronisation des fichiers`), and that `the value cannot have been got back` (`la valeur n'a pas pu être récupérée`).

I cannot acess to my files from it, but it is possible via Internet.

It is written :

> Erreur de synchronisation des fichiers. (org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: Method "current_status" with signature "" on interface "com.ubuntuone.SyncDaemon.Status" doesn't exist.

Do you have some advices?

Thanks

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic. The bug report has already been filed on launchpad here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntuone-control-panel/+bug/858808